# What HASH does OXWALL uses to encrypt its passwords in its database when a user creates an account?

Tags: oxwall

I have tried it but doesnt reflect properly.  Someone please help me...

This is my salt value from config.php

```
define('OW_PASSWORD_SALT', 'xEHNxiEXdz7GK');
```

When i enter the password as 31121993Aa from signing up it generates

```
82416b9973e6fc2279f8e2c54eae6c0d555eae5ad1760985ce1a65b1139c0320
```

But when I create a custom sign up page which inserts data into this table and I use the same password i.e 31121993Aa and I get

```
db57e80826fd86d6b00aebf21b34d1c382e123d17a02a1d008ced708af81441e
```

when i use this code in my php

```
$username=$_POST['username'];
$password=$_POST['password'];
$salt = 'xEHNxiEXdz7GK';
$pass = "password";
$hashit = hash('sha256',$salt.$pass);
$password1=$_POST['password1'];
mysql_query("INSERT INTO oxwa_base_user(username,password,password1,email)VALUES('$username','$hashit','$password1','$mail')");
```

Please help me....

Comment: Lovely [sql injection attack](http://bobby-tables.com) vulnerability. enjoy having your server pwn3d.

Comment: Please help me @MarcB

Comment: @StephnaSouthwark He means that by using code like : $username=$_POST['username'];  for retrieving data on server-side from the $_POST variable  your web application is HIGLY insecure & vulnerable thus higly dangerous for your website members,as well. Follow the link that he provided to get some help.. Good luck!!!!